# eval every line in the scratch buffer and append the result to the line

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got this snippet of code:

```el
(define-key lisp-interaction-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e")
  (lambda ()
    (let ((result (eval (read (buffer-substring 
                               (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))))
          (goto-char (point-at-eol))))
    (insert (format " ; => %s" result))))
```

but it doesn't work, as in

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil (let ((result (eval (read (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))) (goto-char (point-at-eol)))) (insert (format " ; => %s" result)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command shouldn't function on a per-line basis.  Move point by sexp instead.

[Here](https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_libs/blob/master/le-eval-and-insert-results.el) is a library I made that does basically this, but works with mult-line
results, and is reentrant.  So you can change some stuff, and re-run the
command to update results.

EDIT: correct link to package mentioned.

Comment: "Here" link taking no where but here?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```el
(define-key lisp-interaction-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e") 
  (lambda () 
    (interactive)
    (let ((result (eval (read (buffer-substring 
                               (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))))) 
      (goto-char (point-at-eol)) 
      (insert (format " ; ⇒ %s" result)))))
```